# How to run a service for indefinite period of time in android

Tags: android, web-services, service

I am working on an application in which I have to hit the RESTful web service in every 5 min to check whether the new data is updated or not even if the application is closed by the user. I did this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    String url = "http://www.abcert.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    boolean Str;
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.i("JSON",""+jsonArray);


                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");

                           Log.i("MyService is on the",""+id);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.i("Hey","Something went wrong");

                }
            });
    //add request to queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But Didn't get success. START_STICKY is not working when I close the app service is also killed.

Comment: add android:exported="true" in mainfest file wherever service is mentioned.

Comment: what android:exported="true" will work ?

Comment: try it may be you are missing that.

Comment: No it doesnot work ....

Comment: @hitesh try the answer I just posted.

Comment: have you started your service anywhere ?

Comment: @HristoStoyanov Yes i did....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Apps use `Service` which is connected to their DB, for their specific tasks and Run in the background.

Like Facebook runs `MessagingService`, Instagram runs  `NotificationService`. If you want you can use `handler` same time you can also choose `Scheduler`.

Example using `Handler`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

         String url = "http://www.abcert.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                boolean Str;
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("JSON",""+jsonArray);


                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");

                       Log.i("MyService is on the",""+id);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.i("Hey","Something went wrong");

            }
        });

       //add request to queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);     

     handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 60 * 5); //Code runs every 5 minutes
   }
  }, 0); //Initial interval of 0 sec

return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: We are using same code inside Flipkart app, how can you say not working. Try putting toast inside response and track

Comment: Same time you URL is not providing any data , it's a website I guess

Comment: Service is running but when i close the application service is also disabled ... don't know why ...

Comment: Which phone are u testing on?

Comment: Haha, same problem for Xiaomi, see my answer to enable service on Mi phone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973651/android-service-not-restarted/41973677#41973677

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on an application in which I have to hit the RESTful web service in every 5 min to check whether the new data is updated or not even if the application is closed by the user.

Running an indefinite service is not the ideal solution for it. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682130/4738175).

Use a [background scheduler](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/) for this purpose, as it also takes care of efficient usage of the battery.